# mysqldump with multiple triggers

Tags: mysql

I am using mysqldump to create and restore a backup onto another server.

One of the features I am using a lot on this database is triggers. It appears that if there are more than one trigger for any one action on the database the restore is failing because of a dependency on an object (the second trigger) that is not yet created.

The reason seems to be that both trigger declarations contain a reference to each other. But as they are executed in sequence, the first of these fails.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_one
...
PRECEDES trigger_two
...;

[and then a bit further down]

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_two
...
FOLLOWS trigger_one
...;
```

I've separated data and structure and also separated structure as 'just triggers' and 'everything but' following [this article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/02/11/unexpected-problem-with-triggers-and-mysqldump/) on the Percona blog, yet the problem exists and I'd like to be able to automate backups and replication.

Comment: What version of MySQL are using on each server?. Can you show the error message?.

Comment: 5.7.13 on both servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem.

I don't have very clear the MySQL version used in the article of Percona mentioned, but I doubt that is the 5.7 (or at least 5.7.2).

Test:

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.13    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `mytable` (`mycol` BOOL);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_one` BEFORE INSERT ON `mytable`
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    ->   SET NEW.`mycol` := 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_two` BEFORE INSERT ON `mytable`
    -> FOR EACH ROW PRECEDES `trigger_one`
    ->   SET NEW.`mycol` := 2;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

```bsh
$ mysqldump mydatabase > dump.sql
```

```sql
--
-- Table structure for table `mytable`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mytable`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `mycol` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

...

DELIMITER ;;
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`testuser`@`testmachine`*/ 
/*!50003 TRIGGER `trigger_two` BEFORE INSERT ON `mytable`
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.`mycol` := 2 */;;
DELIMITER ;

...

DELIMITER ;;
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`testuser`@`testmachine`*/ 
/*!50003 TRIGGER `trigger_one` BEFORE INSERT ON `mytable`
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.`mycol` := 1 */;;
DELIMITER ;

...
```

> [21.3.1 Trigger Syntax and Examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)
>
> ...
>
> ... To affect trigger order, specify a clause after FOR EACH ROW that
>   indicates FOLLOWS or PRECEDES and the **name of an existing trigger** that
>   also has the same trigger event and action time. ...
>
> ...

Comment: Percona is quoting 5.5. I can perfectly do what you are doing. The issue I am having is that when I run `mysqldump --no-create-info --skip-triggers sakila > data.sql` the first of the two trigger definition containes `PRECEDES trigger_one` I'm running this through MySQL workbench but will try using the command line - which I assumed to be pretty much the same.

Comment: @Hans: Thanks for pointing MySQL version of the article. The documentation says: `mysqldump dumps triggers in activation order so that when the dump file is reloaded, triggers are created in the same activation order.`. [5.5.4 mysqldump — A Database Backup Program](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html), that is why I can't determine where the problem is.

Comment: Yes I saw that, but in my output each trigger contained the full precedes/follows syntax which means there is a cyclic reference. It failes on import. I've even used the 'in one transaction' option.

Comment: @Hans: I can't get `mysqldump` generates an output with `FOLLOWS`, `PRECEDES` or both. See [Support for multiple triggers per table for the same value of action/timing](http://mysqlserverteam.com/support-for-multiple-triggers-per-table-for-the-same-value-of-actiontiming/).

Comment: I know they are optional to configure, but I've configured them before I started restoring backups, so I'm now removing them to just let the default execution order take over. Thanks.